# there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "gimnasio_competencia"

Tags: postgresql

I have the following code in PostGreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE posee_ge
  (
     nombre_gim_comp              VARCHAR(100),
     tiempo_inauguracion_gim_comp SMALLINT,
     rut_entrenador               VARCHAR(50),
     PRIMARY KEY(nombre_gim_comp, tiempo_inauguracion_gim_comp, rut_entrenador)
  );

CREATE TABLE gimnasio_competencia
  (
     nombre                     VARCHAR(100),
     tiempo_inauguracion        SMALLINT,
     cantidad_personas_promedio SMALLINT,
     PRIMARY KEY(nombre, tiempo_inauguracion)
  );

ALTER TABLE posee_ge
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(nombre_gim_comp) REFERENCES gimnasio_competencia(nombre),
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(tiempo_inauguracion_gim_comp) REFERENCES gimnasio_competencia(
  tiempo_inauguracion);
```

And I got the error([See here to view the code online](https://extendsclass.com/postgresql/b84d9f9)):

> there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table
> "gimnasio_competencia".

But all referenced attributes in gimnasio_competencia table are PK(hence UNIQUE and NOT NULL). So, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
ALTER TABLE posee_ge
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(nombre_gim_comp, tiempo_inauguracion_gim_comp) REFERENCES gimnasio_competencia(nombre, tiempo_inauguracion);
```

This should work because (nombre, tiempo_inauguracion) is the PRIMARY KEY of the referenced table gimnasio_competencia.

Comment: yes, that works.